# How to use SMS-Authentication in DocuSign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to implement the SMS authentication with the aid of the DocuSign-SDK library.

```
var signer = new Signer {...};

signer.RequireIdLookup = "true";
signer.IdCheckConfigurationName = "SMS Auth $";
signer.SmsAuthentication = new RecipientSMSAuthentication {
SenderProvidedNumbers = new List<string> {
    "0171*******"  
   }
};
```

When I try to send this envelope to the DocuSign API it will reply with the following error message:

> Error calling CreateEnvelope:
> {"errorCode":"INVALIDAUTHENTICATIONSETUP","message":"Recipient phone
> number is invalid. Phone number for SMS Authentication: provided is
> invalid. }

> INVALIDAUTHENTICATIONSETUP: Authentication is not setup correctly for the recipient.

Is there something I have to enable on the DocuSign Admin page? I couldn't find any feature or something like that I need to enable.

Did I implement it the wrong way? Maybe someone can give me some suggestions.

Thanks

BTW: The given phone number should be valid.

EDIT:

When I'm using the new method as @Inbar wrote, I can't get the needed `workflowId` from the `AccountsApi`.

```
var client = new ApiClient(ApiClient.Demo_REST_BasePath);

var token = "eyJ1...";
client.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

var accountsApi = new AccountsApi(client);    
var response = accountsApi.GetAccountIdentityVerification(accountId);

var result = response.IdentityVerification; // Is empty. Why?
```

It seems that I have no `IdentityVerification` options which I can use for the authentication.

How can I enable such `IdentityVerification` options?

Or what else do I need to pay attention to?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using the older method, the new method code is [provided in GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/RecipientAuthPhone.cs), I'll post it here too. You can find [the article](https://developers-beta.dev.docusign.net/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/) on Dev Center.

```
string workflowId = phoneAuthWorkflow.WorkflowId;

EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition()
{
    EnvelopeIdStamping = "true",
    EmailSubject = "Please Sign",
    EmailBlurb = "Sample text for email body",
    Status = "Sent"
};

byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(docPdf);

// Add a document
Document doc1 = new Document()
{
    DocumentId = "1",
    FileExtension = "pdf",
    Name = "Lorem",
    DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
};

// Create your signature tab
env.Documents = new List<Document> { doc1 };
SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
{
    AnchorString = "/sn1/",
    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    AnchorXOffset = "10",
    AnchorYOffset = "20"
};

// Tabs are set per recipient/signer
Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
{
    SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 }
};


string workflowId = workflowId;

RecipientIdentityVerification workflow = new RecipientIdentityVerification()
{
    WorkflowId = workflowId,
    InputOptions = new List<RecipientIdentityInputOption> {
        new RecipientIdentityInputOption
        {
Name = "phone_number_list",
ValueType = "PhoneNumberList",
PhoneNumberList = new List<RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber>
{
    new RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber
    {
        Number = phoneNumber,
        CountryCode = countryAreaCode,
    }
}
        }
    }
};

Signer signer1 = new Signer()
{
    Name = signerName,
    Email = signerEmail,
    RoutingOrder = "1",
    Status = "Created",
    DeliveryMethod = "Email",
    RecipientId = "1", //represents your {RECIPIENT_ID},
    Tabs = signer1Tabs,
    IdentityVerification = workflow,
};

Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
recipients.Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 };
env.Recipients = recipients;
```

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't retrieve the workflowId via `var response accountsApi.GetAccountIdentityVerification()`. When I call this method the IdentityVerification property is empty. Do I need to enable something on the DocuSign admin page (e.g. https://admindemo.docusign.com/security-settings). I'm using a DocuSign developer account.

Comment: Can you try to create a new developer account? just for testing purposes? try with this new account and tell me if it's same results

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new developer account on DocuSign and created a small test app in order to request identity verification options. Fortunately, that was working now and I got all available options but I do not understand why this is not working for my other developer account ("old").

When I compare both accounts I don't see the "Identity Verification" setting in the "old" account.

[image]

It is possible to activate this "Identity Verification" setting for my "old" dev account?

I guess that enabling this feature would solve the problem.

EDIT:

Ok, I've solved the problem.

I figured out that no IDV was configured for my developer account. In that case, the `identity_verification` call will return an empty array.
see: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/id-verification/

Also, I have read the following note in the DocuSign documentation:

> Note: Phone authentication may not be enabled for some older developer
> accounts. If you cannot choose to use phone authentication for your
> account, contact support to request access. see:
> https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/auth/#id-verification-idv

So I contacted DocuSign support and they give me access to the IDV accordingly.

Now it is working fine.